# To find the eigenvalues of matrix.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $3 \times3$ matrix with trace$(A)=3$ and det$(A)=2$.If  $1$ is an eigen-value of $A$,then the eigen-values of the matrix $A^{2}-2I$ are?

I calculate the eigenvalues of $A$ which comes $1,1+i,1-i.$

So, eigenvalues of $A^{2}$ are $1,2i,-2i.$

So, eigenvalues of $A^{2}-2I$ are $-1,2(i-1),-2(i+1)$.

Is my reasoning correct?

Actually this was the mcq and answer key I have says the different answer giving reason that trace$(A^{2}-2I)$ is $-3$(and I don't find any mistake in their process of deriving this).Is anything wrong with my argument?

Answer (score 2):

Your answer seems to be perfectly fine, possibly the given answer is wrong

Answer (score 1):

I’d guess that the answer key is incorrect. It’s certainly not the first time that has happened.

The trace of $A^2$ is equal to the sum of the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$. According to the key, $\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=3$, but the system $ab=2$, $1+a+b=3$, $1+a^2+b^2=3$ has no solution.

Comment: How you obtain these equations?

Comment: means are they related to $A$ or $A^{2}$

Comment: @omkarGirkar The first two are the sum and product of the eigenvalues of $A$, which must be equal to its trace and determinant, respectively. The last one is the sum of the eigenvalues of $A^2$. (There was an error in the latter two that I’ve fixed.)

Comment: Ok..but $1+a^{2}+b^{2}=1$

Comment: Precisely. The answer key is wrong: $\operatorname{tr}(A^2-2I)$ cannot be equal to $-3$. If it were, then $\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=-3+3\cdot2=3$ and you end up with that inconsistent system of equations for the missing eigenvalues.